# Is it possible to interpolate between CMYK colors without RGB conversion?

Tags: colors, cmyk

I know that I can use bilinear or bicubic interpolation with RGB data. However, RGB is additive color model, while CMYK is subtractive - will it be correct to use the same bilinear/bicubic interpolation when interpolating between CMYK color pixels, without converting to RGB and back?

Comment: it's obviously mathematically possible, but it's going to give different results. I wouldn't say it's "wrong" because what's "right" depends on what you want. Many people would argue that linearly interpolating in RGB is wrong from a human perception model

Comment: @PeterT - different - wildly different, or only imperceptibly? I'm not worried about rounding errors, but I am worried about serious differences.